# Realm MVCC behavior

Tags: java, android, realm

In Realm if Transaction A and B both run as:

Take First Item as "First" => Do Some Long Running Operation => Delete "First"

Will:

- Transaction A and B ever get the same value for "First"?
- Transaction A block Transaction B if it runs "First'?

I'm hoping A blocks the entirety of B because it "writes", then B runs and gets a different value for "First", but it looks like the locking is more fine grained than that and B won't be blocked until it gets to the delete statement.

Does that mean they'll just run with their separate copies of the DB, both get the same value for "First", and run along side each other, then B will throw because it's trying to delete "First" after A already deleted it?

Answer (score 0):

Transactions block each other. Two Realm instances cannot both be in "write" mode at the same time. If a transaction is in progress, then the other thread's Realm instance gets blocked, and is forced to wait until the other transaction is complete. This is why UI thread Realm transactions are discouraged.

During write mode, the Realm sees the "real time newest data" at all times, which used to mean that even as you modified the database, the RealmResults underneath was getting updated in real time. (The fact that this doesn't happen is kind of a "hack" in the Java binding.)

> Transaction A block Transaction B if it runs First?

This wins.